# MRO 3.2.2 for RRE 8.0.0 must be installed and can not be found

Tags: r, visual-studio

Has anyone encountered this error before?

[image]

Basically, I'm trying to install R for Visual Studio 2015.  I downloaded the software from this link.

https://myprodscussu1.app.vssubscriptions.visualstudio.com/Downloads?PId=1962

I'm trying to install RRE for Windows (x64). The 625MB version.  Can someone help me get this working?

Thanks!!

Comment: I haven't seen that exact error, but perhaps this https://mran.revolutionanalytics.com/download/mro-for-mrs/ or https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51205

Comment: Thanks.  I downloaded and installed that.  I still have the same problem.  Ugh.  Is R for Visual Studio available right now?  Is this the Beta version.  Is there a Beta version out now?

Comment: see my comments below...

Answer (score 1):

Ah!  It did work, these are the steps.

```
#1)  Install: 'Revolution-R-Enterprise-8.0.0-Windows.exe'
#2)  Install: 'MRO-3.2.2-for-RRE-8.0.1-Windows.exe'
#3)  Install: 'Revolution-R-Enterprise-Node-8.0.0-Windows.exe'
```

Although, I still don't see R installed in Visual Studio.
[image]

Does anyone know if R is available for Visual Studio 2015?  I hears there is a Beta version out, somewhere, and there will be a full-blown version available anytime now.  If someone has a link to get R for Visual Studio, please do share!

Comment: If you want to see R in Visual Studio, you should install [R Tools for Visual Studio](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/rtvs-vs.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I inadvertently downloaded and installed "RRO-3.2.2-for-RRE-7.5.0-Windows.exe" thinking that it was just an earlier version of the same thing.  But the installers are very different.  The "MRO-3.2.2-for-RRE-8.0.0-Windows.exe" installer provides the options to choose 64-bit components and place registry keys, that the other installer does not.

Once I used the "MRO-3.2.2..." installer, the RRE installer worked properly.